# Magento Catalog Price Rule & Cart Rule - Qty equal or greater than 1

Tags: php, conditional-statements, magento2

When I tried to create a catalog or cart price rule in Magento 2 for products which are in our stock (qty>1), after I saved the rule, the condition became "Quantity equals and grater than In Stock". Also, if I am using "Quantity is not 0", the condition became "Quantity is not Out of Stock".

Thanks for support!

I want to display 10% discount for products of supplier X and with qty > 1 (means that the product is in stock in our inventory).